# Spring Boot Validation gives Bad Request

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, pojo, bad-request

My pom:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

My Controller:

@RestController
@Validated

methodName(@Valid @RequestBody POJO_NAME)

My POJO

```
@Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z0-9]{30}",message="uniqueId length must be 30")
    private String uniqueId;

    @Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z0-9]{50}",message="authId length must be 50")
    private String authId;
```

Whenever I try to hit the post request (with and without valid values) I get below in postman

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-11-24T16:51:26.733+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "path": "path/to/post/request"
}
```

Kindly help me find out what is missing in my code that is preventing validation from working as expected.

Comment: Can you please share curl request for both scenarios?

Comment: Bad curl with uniqueId more than 30 characters: curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/servicecatalogue/ECOM/1234/inquiry' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '"authId": "userId",
"authPassword": "************",
"serviceId": "1984120645",
"uniqueId": "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz",
"serviceAmount": 100,
"quantity": 2'

Comment: Is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

The curl request mentioned in the comment looks incorrect that's why a Bad Request (Status code - 400) coming. I can see curly braces ({}) are missing after `-data-raw`

Please try with this curl request

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8080/servicecatalogue/ECOM/1234/inquiry' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "authId": "userId",
    "authPassword": "************",
    "serviceId": "1984120645",
    "uniqueId": "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz",
    "serviceAmount": 100,
    "quantity": 2
}'
```